# how to display Notification when app is close and hide when app is open in notification Manager

Tags: android

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
        return activityVisible;
    }

    public static void activityResumed() {
        activityVisible = true;

    }

    public static void activityPaused() {
        activityVisible = false;
    }

    private static boolean activityVisible;
    public static String FID = "";

}
```

Condition for App is open then dont show notification and if app is close show notification .

```
if(LociiApplication.isActivityVisible())
                            System.out.println("Dont show notifications!");
                        else
                            sendNotification(msg, senderID);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
```

Actually i want apply one condition from which when app is Open there is not notification should display in Notification manger when app is close then Notification should display . i am trying to implement like that way but its not working

Comment: where you are calling `activityResumed` and `activityPaused` method ?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will return true if your app is in foreground else it will return false

```
 public boolean isAppInForeground(Context mCtx) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager
                .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        boolean isAppInForeGround = false;

        if (services.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().toString()
                .equalsIgnoreCase(mCtx.getPackageName().toString())) {
            isAppInForeGround = true;
        }

      return isAppInForeGround;
    }
```

Comment: I have to call this in GCMIntent Service

Comment: if (isAppInForeground(context)==true)
     System.out.println("Dontshow Notification");
    else
     sendNotification(msg, senderID); this code i have apply in GCmIntent service class

Comment: Yes you have to call this in following lines if(isAppInForeground(mCtx))
                            System.out.println("Dont show notifications!");
                        else
                            sendNotification(msg, senderID);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/MchiMAzRNSavjyqcUmzJCb  am trying in this way but now all case when app open or close no notification show in Notification Manger

Comment: change your if block to this  if (shownotificationcheckbox.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

     if(isAppInForeground(getApplicationContext()))
     System.out.println("Dontshow Notification");
    else
     sendNotification(msg, senderID);
   }

Comment: not working Notification Not coming when App is closed

Comment: what is the value of shownotificationcheckbox?

Comment: its comingin 1and this i have to apply for handle Notification from setting in checkbox